# Google Analytics on Android problems

Tags: android, google-analytics

I setup Google Analytics for my Android app. When I test it with the Android Studio emulator everything works fine and I can see the events in real time on the Google Analytics web console.

If I put the app on my phone (debug or signed with keystore) and I watch the log I can see that the hit are created and sent just fine but I can't see them on the web console. I tried to wait 2-3 days and I tried to submit the app to see if other users' devices would work but the only results I see are the ones from my local emulator and the ones from Google's pre-launch reports (so emulators again).

The same thing happens when I try with the sample app available on the developer guide ([Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/start)), so it's definitely not my code. What am I missing?

Comment: What make / model is the phone?